# Google sheets with conditional formatting not working

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

**Update:**
I want one specific cell to become green (filled with green color) if a range of other cells (which contain only dates) count up to 7 or more filled cells AND contain dates within a specific date range.

I have created a logical function which is *true* but as soon as I want to use it for the conditional formatting the color labeling doesn't work.
Is there a specific reason why the following formula works (=becoming true) in a cell but not in the conditional formatting?

```
=AND(A2:A>=DATE(2017;10;12);A2:A<=DATE(2017;10;19);COUNTA(A2:A)>6)
```

I have a feeling that it is related to the DATE range filter but don't know exactly.

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uH2PZ9YmFNQDmml73iKQNz6sv8tEwbETRo0ywxz6yg4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The formula works for me. Add more details like the address of cells where you applied the conditional formatting.

Comment: Take a look at this example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uH2PZ9YmFNQDmml73iKQNz6sv8tEwbETRo0ywxz6yg4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the edit,

> Update: I want one specific cell to become green (filled with green color) if a range of other cells (which contain only dates) count up to 7 or more filled cells AND contain dates within a specific date range.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND($A$2:INDEX($A$2:$A,COUNTA($A$2:$A))>=DATE(2017,10,12),$A$2:INDEX($A$2:$A,COUNTA($A$2:$A))<=DATE(2017,10,19),COUNTA($A$2:$A)>6))
```

Apply to `A1`

This should work, as long as **`ALL`** the dates (with no exception) in A column are within the date  range specified.

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND(SUMPRODUCT($A$2:INDEX($A$2:$A,COUNTA($A$2:$A))>=DATE(2017,10,12))>6,SUMPRODUCT($A$2:INDEX($A$2:$A,COUNTA($A$2:$A))<=DATE(2017,10,19))>6))
```

Apply  to `A1`

This should work, If any 7 or more of the entries in column A are within the specified date range.

---

---

Note: For both the formulas to work, There shouldn't be any blanks in between two entries.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND(SUMPRODUCT($A$2:A>=DATE(2017,10,12))>6,SUMPRODUCT($A$2:A<=DATE(2017,10,19))>6))
```

This will work in spite of blank entries, if any 7 or more of the entries are within the date range.

**Tested and works well**

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the second version and it works as it was intended by me. Have a great weekend!